# How to get value of a input field in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using valums-file-uploader plugin. It allows me to upload files using ajax. I have a problem with it. I have the following script-

```
<input type="text" id="Gaurav" name="Gaurav" />
<script src="fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function createUploader(){
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file'),
            action: 'do-nothing.php',
            params:{param: document.getElementById('Gaurav').value},
            allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
            minSizeLimit: 1,
            debug: false
        });
    }

    // in your app create uploader as soon as the DOM is ready
    // dont wait for the window to load  
    window.onload = createUploader;     
</script>
```

In it, I want to set the value of param entered by the user. The code is working properly for default value of Gaurav, but didn't work for user inputted value.

Comment: The uploader is created with that value when the window loads, it doesn't magically change when the input value changes

Comment: Which library/framework/plugin is that? Please link to it / tag your question - it does not seem to be jQuery.ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `createUploader` *after* the user has entered a value. This code is 'fixing' the param value as soon as the window loads.

You may have a button click event or something - call it from that and it will take the value *at that time*...

Comment: On the place of window.onload, I wrote-var g= document.getElementById('Gaurav'); g.onblur= creatUploader;

Answer (score 2):

You set a param to your function (the value you want to push) and call the function when the user writes something inside the input. 
*The param is in fact optional because your function gets the value from the input itself but it is more efficient to pass the argument as you skip the DOM search.

```
<input type="text" id="Gaurav" name="Gaurav" onchange="createUploader($(this).val())" />
<script src="fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function createUploader(value){
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file'),
            action: 'do-nothing.php',
            params:{param: value,
            allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
            minSizeLimit: 1,
            debug: false
        });
    }

    // in your app create uploader as soon as the DOM is ready
    // dont wait for the window to load  
    window.onload = createUploader($("#Gaurav").val());     
</script>
```

Comment: It s also set on the onchange event.